# jQuery ajax get request not working with IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I use this code to detect changes to a form and then perform a get request using the serialized form data. This works in all browsers that I have tested on. But I'm on a mac and now I get emails from people saying that it doesn't work in IE 11. What could be wrong?

Error message: "webpage.com is not responding due to a long running script"

I've tried testing this myself using IE 11 in a VirtualBox but the webpage becomes unresponsive as soon as I change something to the form. I'm not sure how to find out what's wrong.. I have no loops so I don't get why this script would make the page unresponsive.

Please help.

```
jQuery('.appselect').change(function(e) {
 if (jQuery(window).width() > 800) {
  jQuery.get('/?' + jQuery('#appfilter').serialize(), function(data) {
    jQuery('#postloop').replaceWith( jQuery(data).find('#postloop') );

    if (!jQuery('#pagination').length) {
      jQuery('#postloop').after(jQuery(data).find('#pagination'));
    } else {
      jQuery('#pagination').replaceWith(jQuery(data).find('#pagination'));
    }
  });
 }
});
```

This is a wordpress page, but I think the problem is not related to Wordpress. I'm using jQuery 1.11.1.

Comment: did you try to comment all the code inside the callback? So we can understand if the problem is the ajax call or the code inside the callback

Comment: yes. removing all code inside the callback will make the error go away. Keeping this line, and browser becomes unresponsive:

    jQuery('#postloop').replaceWith( jQuery(data).find('#postloop') );

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var html = jQuery(data).find('#postloop').html();
jQuery('#postloop').html(html);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But that didn't help. Webpage becomes unresponsive just like before.

Comment: could you try to comment the second row jQuery('#postloop').html(html); and look if still hangs?

Comment: If I comment the second row as suggested, the error goes away. If I keep the second row jQuery('#postloop').html(html) it still hangs.

Comment: It seems as if it is caused by a adsense ad that is a part of the html I try to inject